# Pandas: How to format Series to Datetime when it has multiple date formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, formatting

I am trying to convert all dates to a datetime datatype but I have a series that has two different formats.

## Context

I have no control over in how we receive this dataset. Unfortunately our client send it to us using `%d/%m/%Y` format. I am importing the data from excel but excel formats some of the dates such that it imports it as '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'. I convert the date column to string and below is what I've tried.

## My Code

---

```
import pandas as pd

dates_str = pd.Series(['2020-03-01 00:00:00', '23/01/20', '2020-06-01 00:00:00', '24/01/20', '2020-06-25 00:00:00', '13/01/20'])

date_formats = ['%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y']

for date_format in date_formats:
    try:
        dates_str = pd.to_datetime(arg=dates_str, format=date_format) # try to get the date
        break # if correct format, don't test any other formats
    except ValueError:
        pass # if incorrect format, keep trying other formats
```

I know the reason it does not work is because the Try Except exception handler is not looping through through each row. I know that I can just loop through each row myself but that is definitely not the most efficient way.

Comment: Have you looked at dateutils: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html might help

Answer (score 0):

if you apply pd.to_datetime on the dates_str series, it does convert the type to M8, which is a specific datetime type. Isn't this good enough? :)

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` `to_datetime` does a good job parsing the strings from your example:

```
import pandas as pd

dates_str = pd.Series(['2020-03-01 00:00:00', '23/01/20', '2020-06-01 00:00:00', 
                       '24/01/20', '2020-06-25 00:00:00', '13/01/20'])

pd.to_datetime(dates_str, dayfirst=True)
Out[2]: 
0   2020-03-01
1   2020-01-23
2   2020-06-01
3   2020-01-24
4   2020-06-25
5   2020-01-13
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```